How do I read predicate logic formulas using proper english not the one used by mathematicans?
Question.
How do I reed predicate logic formulas in proper english, not one used by mathematicans? Im interesint in precieving formulas audially not visually. I am interested in simple set of rules how can I transform formulas to natural language forth and back.
Example
(x)[(Ey)(A(x,y)->B(x,y))->((Ey)(A(x,y)->C(x,y))].
My attempt
First of all I would draw a semantic three for a relation. Than I would read it. I will treat universalities and existences as relations.
Implication is universal to x.
Where left implications part is existence from y to impilcation.
Where2 implication is from A to B.
Where3 A is from x to y
Where3 B is from x to y
Where right implication part is existance from y to implication.
Where2 implication is from A to B.
Where3 A is from x to y.
Where3 C is from x to y.
Relevance.
I can do ZFC proofs using standart notation and pen, but I can't use it say for reasoning about who is real father of some Santabarbora character. So I want to do proofs not on the paper but vocally.
Update.
I have read 6.5 book on logic. I know how mathematicans usually do read small formulas, like: there is a cat who loves  all dogs. I am interested in longer formulas, where are reapeated same relations. One of the way to do this is using sort of xml like syntax, but it is bad for preception. So I wondered wether there are means of expressing this information in natural to english way, in a such a way for it to be easily precieved audially. I did treat quantifiers as relation for simlisity. I don't care how "grammatically correct" will be the translation, all I care is how natural it will sound. So I want to use translations for reasoning.

your parentheses are mismatched

Is this correct? (x): [(Ey: A(x,y) -> B(x,y)) -> (Ez: A(x,z) -> C(x,z))]

Yes. Sorry i missed that.

Santabarbara was one if the first soap operas, soviet people saw. So it became proper name for soap operas. Usually one gets easily involved in it. Usially one is invovled in reasoning in thing what will happen is next series. Usually they say something like "in next series you will see who is real father of some Huan Pedros". So I used it as proper name for dayly robust reasoning.

This isn't a philosophy question. You could ask it on Math SE. However, ultimately, there is no substitute for learning to read the languages that you are working with, and that includes formal logical notation. There is a notion of mathematical English, which would read: "For all x, if there exists a y such that if A holds on x and y then B holds on x and y, then there exists a z such that if A holds on x and z, then C holds on x and z." This is a limited "audiovisual isomorphism", a multimedia connection used by working mathematicians to communicate.

Predicate logic and English have different syntax and grammar and even different logical vocabulary, so there is no simple set of rules that will translate them. There are heuristics that translate predicate logic to English pretty well. But translating a natural language such as English into formal logic is a very hard problem. Natural languages did not evolve to express the highly specific requirements of formulas in formal logic. And on the other hand, natural languages contain a great deal that cannot be stated in first-order logic.
Some rules of thumb for translating predicate logic into English are:

Start with the simple meanings of 'and', 'or' and 'not'. Bear in mind that 'or' is ambiguous between inclusive and exclusive use in English. Even when you combine it with the word 'either' it can still have the inclusive sense. You can force the exclusive sense with "and not both"; you can force the inclusive sense with "or both" or "and/or".

The existential, ∃, can be translated as "at least one". It is often written as 'some' but that only works if it is a known convention that 'some' means at least one.

The universal, ∀, can be translated as 'all', 'every', or 'any', or their relatives 'everything', 'everybody', 'anything', 'anybody', etc. 'All' can be used with both mass nouns and count nouns; 'every' is not used with mass nouns. ∀ in formal logic does not have existential import, while 'all' in English often does by virtue of conversational implicature. "All my children are asleep" is an odd thing to say if you have no children. You may wish to explicitly state that a universally quantified predicate may be empty.


'Any' often gives a clearer translation than 'all', but there is a catch with 'any'. When 'any' appears embedded within an expression, it has a strong tendency to force itself to have the widest scope in the sentence or clause. Some examples may help to make this clearer. In a simple sentence with no embedded expressions, 'any' and 'every' are the same:
Any member in good standing is eligible to vote. 
Every member in good standing is eligible to vote. (Same) 

Now contrast a simple pair with a negated pair:
I understand any Japanese sentence. 
I understand every Japanese sentence. (Same) 

I do not understand any Japanese sentence. 
I do not understand every Japanese sentence. (Different) 

Likewise when 'any' is embedded in a modal expression:
You may choose to eat any dessert. 
You may choose to eat every dessert. (Different)

Or where 'any' is embedded in a conditional expression:
If you answer any question correctly, you'll pass. 
If you answer every question correctly, you'll pass. (Different) 

The difference lies in the fact that 'every' and 'all' are happy to sit inside the scope of an operator, but 'any' typically requires a wide scope interpretation. So, for example, the last two examples are distinguished by being glossed as:
For every question the following holds: if you answer it correctly, you'll pass. (Wide scope)
If you answer correctly the following: every question, you'll pass.  (Narrow scope) 

[It is curious that many sources, including sites covering English usage, get this wrong and claim that 'any' is ambiguous and sometimes means 'some'. It doesn't. It's just a scoping issue. Though there are situations where 'some' can mean 'any'.]

The material conditional is best translated as if/then. Mathematicians are usually taught to read it as 'implies' but this is potentially misleading because it invites confusion between material implication and logical implication or logical consequence. Great care is needed with conditionals because the logic of conditionals is complex and many conditional expressions in English are not correctly represented by the material conditional.

There is an example of this in the formula you give. It contains an existential quantifier in front of an expression whose main connective is a material conditional. Whenever you see this, an alarm bell should sound in your head. It doesn't mean what it looks like it should mean. For example, consider the formula:
(∃x)(Fx → Gx) 

It is tempting to think that this means "there is something such that if it is F then it is G". But this is incorrect. (∃x)(Fx → Gx) is true if (∃x)(¬Fx) and is also true if (∃x)(Gx).

Formulas that contain several variables will be difficult to express in English. It is natural to use pronouns to translate variables, but once you have more than two it becomes difficult to disambiguate them.


Thank you. The main pourpuce for me why I asked the question is this. When I reason, I usually do it with words, so i am using relations beteen audial symbols only. When I solve equations I reason visually. So idea was to try to combine predicate logic with my usial reasoning way. So I guess I need to invent the language of my own.

You want the "read as" column at wiki: list of logic symbols.
A similar list for a backup in case of link failure.
Any introductory formal logic textbook should also have what you need.

I have read 6.5 books on logic. I know how to read formulas. I want sort of solve them by reasoning audially about formulas in the same way I might reason about say Santabarbara.

I also know something about "translating predicate logic to english". What I am realy am interested is how to deal with nested "witch" clauses.
